# Adding value to array inside object PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have this object:

```
$myobject = (object) [  
    'name' => [],
    'value' => [],
    'id' => [],
];
```

I want to add some values in a for each loop, but array push does not seem to work.

**I've tried this:**

```
$object_name = $myobject->name;
array_push($object_name, "testName");
```

I've looked everywhere but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: `array_push($myobject->name, "testName");`

Comment: `$object->name[] = 'testName';`?

Comment: Thanks @Jon, that worked!  Nospor, that didn't work for me earlier, maybe I did something wrong though, but thanks for helping out!

Can't mark anything as a right answer, but if you post it as an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark it as a right answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cann't use array_push this way. `$object_name` is not your main object.

When you push to `$object_name`, your `$myobject` is still empty.

You can fix it adding reference `&`, for example:

```
$object_name = &$myobject->name;
```

or just push to your original object:

```
array_push($myobject->name, "testName");
```

or

```
$myobject->name[] = "something";
```

Answer (score 2):

Simple option is to add another item to the property using normal array notation.

e.g.

`$object->name[] = 'testName';`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$names = ['A', 'B', 'C'];  /* This is an array of names */

foreach ($names as $name) {
    $myobject->name[] = $name;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r($myobject);
```