# Add a value to existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of data:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
    [name] => admin
    [email] => admin@adminmail.com 
    [password] => cxvxvcxvcxv
  )
)
```

I want to add a new data to this array so the final array looks like:

```
Array( [0] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
    [name] => admin
    [email] => admin@adminmail.com 
    [password] => cxvxvcxvcxv
    [enabled] => true
  )
)
```

I tried array_merge(), but it gives me result like this:

```
Array( [0] => stdClass Object 
  ( 
    [name] => admin
    [email] => admin@adminmail.com 
    [password] => cxvxvcxvcxv
  )
  [enabled] => true
)
```

How do I achieve the result I want?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding value to array inside object PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37920697/adding-value-to-array-inside-object-php)

Comment: you want to add new property to an existing class, not to an array !

Comment: it's object. You can't use array merge

Comment: @splash58 sorry i updated my question, it's an array with an object inside the first index and I want to add [enabled] => true in my object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myArray[0]->enabled = 'true';
```

Just add the new field straight into your object and assign the value you want to it. This should do the trick for you.

If you array has multiple nested arrays you will need a loop though. My code will only work for position 0 like you asked.

Comment: will that work if i want to save enabled as a boolean value?

Comment: Of course just remove the single quotes if you want to have it in a boolean value. Give it a try. Keep in mind that true is 1 and false is 0. If you want to have it as a word then you can use it like a string as have in my example.